# Vue js triggering a method/function every x seconds

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.6

The title pretty much explains it, but i am looking to fire of a function every second.

I haven't tried anything, nor do i have much code that would be useful.

I have done some googling around and so far had n joy with any examples.

Also, i am using laravel 5.6

this doesn't work, for calling the **countDown()** method

```
export default {
    ready() {
        window.setInterval(() => {
            this.countDown();
        },1000);
    },
```

Comment: How exactly does it _"not work"_? When / where are you calling the `ready()` function?

Comment: I believe he must be having an error as this will get lost in setInterval callback. Is it ? Do you see any error in your console ?

Comment: there is no lifecycle hook named `ready`. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

Answer (score 31):

Just to combine the solutions (since I'm unable to edit), the code below works. One gotcha is that you also want the job to stop once the view is destroyed, so you'll want to clear it when the `beforeDestroy` hook is called

```js
mounted: function () {
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.countDown()
  }, 1000)
},

data() {
  return {
    timer: null
  }
},

beforeDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.timer)
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer! No need to use window object. Also it's great to destroy the interval if it's not needed anymore.

Comment: For Vue3, use `beforeUnmount` hook instead of `beforeDestroy`

Answer (score 24):

The answer posted above is triggered every second (because of $nextTick) so in case you want to set a different interval, just remove the $nextTick ( In my case I set it to 30000 since I had to fire it every 30 seconds)

```
mounted: function () {
  window.setInterval(() => {
    this.getNotifications()
  }, 30000)
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Thanks guys, i found the solution, just took a bit of asking the right questions in google :)

```
mounted: function () {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            window.setInterval(() => {
                this.countDown();
            },1000);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Why use `$nextTick`? Your interval callback will wait one second before beginning to execute anyway

Comment: i didn't realise that is what it did, was the first working solution i found

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. This one works for me.

```
created() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getNotifications(), 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works best as it makes sure the interval is cleared before the component is destroyed without defining anything in data.

```
created: function() {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.countDown();
  }, 1000);

  this.$once("hook:beforeDestroy", () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Vue3 Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html)

```js
<script setup>

import { onMounted, onBeforeUnmount, ref } from "vue";

const timer = ref();

function countDownFunc() {
console.log("Running countDownFunc")
...
}

// Instantiate
onMounted(() => {
  timer.value = setInterval(() => {
    countDownFunc();
  }, 3000);
});

// Clean up
onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  timer.value = null;
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Vue3 docs: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onunmounted

With composition API

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

let intervalId;

function checkInstance() {
  console.log("checkInstance")
}

onMounted(() => {
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    checkInstance();
  }, 3000);
});

onUnmounted(() => clearInterval(intervalId))
</script>
```

To use it with async/await, change the onMounted:

```js
onMounted(async () => {
  intervalId = setInterval(async() => {
    Instances.value = await checkInstance();
  }, 3000);
});
```